# Angular Google Maps map click event works once

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, angular-google-maps

I've been having a problem very similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32597105/angular-google-maps-click-event-cannot-read-property-click-of-undefined)

However that persons question was never answered and my situation is subtly different.

I'm trying to add a click event to my map that will change the center of the map to the location of the click. My code to do this works great, but it only works once and then when I click again I get this error:

`angular-google-maps.js:6815 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'click' of undefined`

Here is my map object:

```
vm.map = {
     center: {
          latitude: l.latitude,
          longitude: l.longitude
     },
     zoom: 13,
     events: {
          click: function(map, event, coords) {
               vm.map = {
                    center: {
                         latitude: coords[0].latLng.lat(),
                         longitude: coords[0].latLng.lng()
                    },
               };

               $scope.apply();

           }
     }
};
```

And here's my html:

```
<ui-gmap-google-map center="location.map.center" zoom="location.map.zoom" draggable="true" options="tabLocations.map.options" events=location.map.events>
    <ui-gmap-search-box template="'scripts/components/tab-locations/searchbox.tpl.html'" events="location.map.searchbox.events" parentdiv="'searchbox-container'"></ui-gmap-search-box>
    <ui-gmap-marker ng-if="location.active" idKey="1" coords="location" options="{draggable: false, icon: 'images/icons/gps-marker-active.svg'}"></ui-gmap-marker>
    <ui-gmap-marker ng-if="!location.active" idKey="1" coords="location" options="{draggable: false, icon: 'images/icons/gps-marker-inactive.svg'}"></ui-gmap-marker>
</ui-gmap-google-map>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your first click you are redefining a brand new map with no click event:

```
vm.map = {
    center: {
        latitude: coords[0].latLng.lat(),
        longitude: coords[0].latLng.lng()
    },
};
```

This is overriding all the previous properties you had set before, which includes `click`.

Use `setCenter` instead:

```
click: function(map, event, coords) {

    var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude: coords[0].latLng.lat(), latitude: coords[0].latLng.lng());
    vm.map.setCenter(latLng);

}
```

Reference: [Google Maps API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Map)

Comment: This is perfect! Thank you!